# Does the "Create installation media for Windows 8.1" have all the most recent updates?

Tags: windows-8

I ran across the [Create installation media for Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) page on Microsoft's site. Does anyone know if the "media" it creates contains all the latest updates or is it just the same bits from the original 8.1 launch and the updates have to be applied through windows update?

Comment: @TugboartCaptain - No;  The last installation media Microsoft would have been the Update 2 released in December and they didn't.

Comment: @Ramhound: Are you saying the ISO downloaded via this Media Creation Tool doesn't include Update 2? Is that something you've personally observed or is there some authoritative online resource you can point to? I'm asking because the Tool did download an ISO with Update 1 for a friend of mine (back when Update 2 hadn't been released of course).

Comment: @Karan - Microsoft did not release an updated .ISO for Spring Update (i.e. Update 2 ).  They only updated the .ISO  for Update 1, is required to get future updates, for Windows 8.1.  To answer your specific question, the tool will download the current .ISO, and that would be an .ISO with Update 1.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I just thought they'd have updated this ISO for Update 2 as well, especially since the MSDN one was naturally updated.

Comment: It could have been updated, but I recently downloaded it, and didn't include Update 2.